# Which of Cypher components are case sensitive in Cypher query?

Tags: cypher, graph-databases, memgraphdb

Is Cypher case sensitive or not? I've read a lot of different things. Some say yes, others no. Does it depend on the graph database and Cypher flavor that you use?

Comment: Neo4j Cypher is case sensitive for sure. It caused me a lot of issues at first. 

Comment: Thanks, Vincent. I've searched for old Stack overflow questions and it seems that it is better to treat it as if it is always case-sensitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Cypher query language is case-sensitive. This is true for property values as well as labels. Clauses are not case-sensitive.